# How to redefine return types for methods with Proxy in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to promisify all methods in a class with Proxy like this:

```js
class Person {
  id = 1
  getName(): string {
    return "name"
  }

  getAge(): number {
    return 1
  }
}

const person = new Person();

const asyncPerson = new Proxy(person, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    let fn = Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver)
    if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
      return fn
    }
    return (...args: any[]) => {
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        try {
          res(fn.apply(receiver, args))
        } catch (err) {
          rej(err)
        }
      }) 
    }
    
  }
})

console.log(asyncPerson.id)
console.log(asyncPerson.getName())
```

The problem is that typescript thinks `asyncPerson` is of type `Person`. Any way to define a new  type that correctly reflects the type of `asyncPerson` without having to manually type out all `Person`'s methods?

OTOH, is there a way to automatically define a "promisified" class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to create a "promisified" version of a type:

```
type Promisified<T> = { 
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer R
        ? (...args: A) => Promise<R>
        : T[K] 
};
```

The above utility will wrap the return type of methods with promise.

Another caveat is that `Proxy` constructor definition always returns the same as the input type. To overcome this `new Proxy<any>` can be used or double type assertion.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGtAlgCbQC80AjLtAObwAuAcmALbwAUAlAFzQR2L401LFTyJ6AV0QYARGhbwZVAL7YqtOgEFanHmgnMARkhF4xk6RRXZV2OgE8ADvDiIUzfBHwAzfPEIAPAAqAHykWNCi0ADaANIEGADW8PYo3tBBALo8QXGZ0PAAHnTwaIQwbAB01WCI1BA8gt4mmhykYU0mAEpRZtAA-NBVNXUN0K3tru6e8AFdIb1mOXmRygDcasDofNDOyOjhaPAA7nBIqGicG9hbaDuQ9mjACPtoPLBuHl6%20-gEvF2EyEdTh8UIV7AEwGh7CE2HsLgAaUw0ehsOi1DRIxxuRxI8TAeD4ABuSDaOD6IHo0G8GDIXXg3kpwDolQ0aIx9CxOLx8AJxNJUR8QwczjS1IwAEISGQAOTeCRPOj4dAysmLcR0KQYGlRVR9DVaobVSoYsZQ%20zRTJtEhhcl9aAGyzAqZfdhscQQHkAK2ttsWeH49mR9rMHrYNJNjkcIHs7t5hJJiCRpo4HH90GU0GAYDowAAFkMkIg1SH9fAvWwi2nSxnFso2rqotZ65ttihKZUQChqGwHk9-uhKkQ07dUB2uz2%2089zoONExWJwOEA)